# Confusing result when using where.not with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I've got an orders model with a payment status string field. Ordinarily this field should be populated but sometimes it's nil. I have the following scope

```
scope :not_pending, -> { where.not(payment_status: 'pending') }
```

In one of my tests, the payment_status is nil for an order but I still get an empty result for the scope. If I change it to remove the .not, I get an empty result again so I'm a bit confused.

EDIT - Added SQL

```
"SELECT "orders".* FROM "orders" INNER JOIN "order_compilations" ON "orders"."id" = "order_compilations"."order_id" WHERE "order_compilations"."menu_group_id" = 3724 AND ("orders"."payment_status" != 'pending')"
```

Comment: see the generated SQL statements and run them in your test database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `nil` along, then it will check both

```
scope :not_pending, -> { where.not(payment_status: 'pending').or(payment_status: nil) }
```

which is equivalent to `where("payment_status <> 'pending' OR payment_status IS NULL")`

**UPDATE**
changed to include nil

Comment: have you tried this code, i feel it'll not be able to pull the data since rails have nil stored while it'll look for NULL. I'm not sure though

Comment: I'd like results to show up with a nil value, which it currently doesn't. Your suggestion would definitely exclude nil values, which is what I have already unfortunately, although not out of choice. Sorry if I wasn't clear in my question.

Comment: 'or' is only in Rails 5 but the second version seems to work a treat. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is not because of Rails but because it's how SQL actually works.
`!=` means something different, but still something. `NULL` is not something.

You can see [this related issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/19262).

Answer (score 1):

In SQL, a NULL value in an expression will always evaluate the expression to false. The theory is that a NULL value is unknown, not just an empty value that you could evaluate to 0, or false.

So for example, `1 = NULL` is false, but `1 != NULL` is false too.

So in your case, I would probably write:

```
where("payment_status != 'pending' or payment_status is null")
```